# Replicate rows in Pandas and add a new (month) column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am struggling with what I am sure is a simple problem. I have a dataframe that has around `1000 rows` that are unique.

This shows `expenses for the year` by category by location. Each has location the same group of categories.

I want to create a `monthly budget` column for each expense per site.

I also want to create a year to date budget column that takes the total budget for the year and divides it by 12 to give a monthly figure. This is then multiplied by the month (April = month 1) to give a year to date value - e.g May will be monthly figure * 2 etc.

I am trying to use pandas to do this. I have tried

```
    pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(budget.values,12,axis=0)) #replicate each row by 12
```

My plan was then to iterate through each row in each group to add the month but I am struggling to achieve anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

(apologies I can not get the tables to paste properly - please see pictures)

Current

```
+------------+-------------+--------+
|  Location  |  Expense    | Amount |
+------------+-------------+--------+
| Sheffield  | Electricity |  10000 |
| Sheffield  | Gas         |  12000 |
| Manchester | Electricity |  15000 |
| Manchester | Electricity |  13000 |
+------------+-------------+--------+
```

Desired

```
+------------+-------------+--------+--------+---------+-------+
|  Location  |  Expense    | Amount | Budget |  Month  |  YTD  |
+------------+-------------+--------+--------+---------+-------+
| Sheffield  | Electricity |  10000 |  10000 | April   |  1000 |
| Sheffield  | Electricity |  10000 |  10000 | May     |  2000 |
| Sheffield  | Electricity |  10000 |  10000 | June    |  3000 |
| Sheffield  | Electricity |  10000 |  10000 | July    |  4000 |
| Sheffield  | Electricity |  10000 |  10000 | August  |  5000 |
| Sheffield  | Electricity |  10000 |  10000 | Sep     |  6000 |
| Sheffield  | Electricity |  10000 |  10000 | Oct     |  7000 |
| Sheffield  | Electricity |  10000 |  10000 | Dec     |  8000 |
| Sheffield  | Electricity |  10000 |  10000 | Jan     |  9000 |
| Sheffield  | Electricity |  10000 |  10000 | Feb     | 10000 |
| Sheffield  | Electricity |  10000 |  10000 | March   | 11000 |
| Sheffield  | Gas         |  12000 |  20000 | April   |  2000 |
| Sheffield  | Gas         |  12000 |  20000 | May     |  4000 |
| Sheffield  | Gas         |  12000 |  20000 | June... |  6000 |
| Sheffield  | Gas         |  12000 |  20000 | ..March |  8000 |
| Manchester | Electricity |  15000 |  36000 | April   |  4000 |
| Manchester | Electricity |  15000 |  36000 | May     |  8000 |
+------------+-------------+--------+--------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Please add some sample data in the text form.

Comment: whats the logic for calculating the YTD column ?

Comment: @Grayrigel - apologies - I have now reposted using text form

Comment: @Manakin  - the YTD is calculated by Budget / 12 and then multiplying this by the calendar year in the Month column. It is essentially the yearly Budget (Budget column) divided into a monthly amount, and then this is made cumulative over the year - e.g. April YTD = 1*(budget/12), May YTD = 2*(budget/12), June YTD  = 3*(budget/12). 

April is month 1 as this is the start of the financial year. 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your specific month-table with April as the number 1 for the starting month in the fiscal year.

```
import pandas as pd 
  
# intialise data from list. 
data = {'Month':['April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March'], \
        'Number':range(1,13), \
        'key': [1] * 12 }

  
# Create DataFrame 
df_months = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Resulting in a table like this:

```
+------------+--------+-----+
| Month      | Number | key |
+------------+--------+-----+
| April      |  1     | 1   |
| May        |  2     | 1   |
| June       |  3     | 1   |
| July       |  4     | 1   |
| August     |  5     | 1   |
| September  |  6     | 1   |
| October    |  7     | 1   |
| November   |  8     | 1   |
| December   |  9     | 1   |
| January    |  10    | 1   |
| February   |  11    | 1   |
| March      |  12    | 1   |
+------------+--------+-----+
```

Now adapt your second table, let's call it `df_amounts` to have a ficitonal key-column (`key`) which will ensure every month gets joined to every location/expense combination:

```
df_amounts['key'] = 1
```

df_amounts:

```
+------------+-------------+--------+-----+
|  Location  |  Expense    | Amount | key |
+------------+-------------+--------+-----+
| Sheffield  | Electricity |  10000 | 1   |
| Sheffield  | Gas         |  12000 | 1   |
| Manchester | Electricity |  15000 | 1   |
| Manchester | Electricity |  13000 | 1   |
+------------+-------------+--------+-----+
```

Then join the tables on `key`:

```
df = pd.merge(df_amounts, df_months, on="key", how="left")
```

To get the following table:

```
+------------+-------------+--------+-----+-------+--------+
|  Location  |  Expense    | Amount | key | Month | Number | 
+------------+-------------+--------+-----+-------+--------+
```

Now divide the column `number` by `12` and multiply the value with `Amount` to get your new column `YTD`.

```
df['YTD']= df['Amount'] * (df['Number'] / 12)
```

Your monthly `Budget` column works similarly:

```
df['Budget']= df['Amount'] / 12
```